# Compute the $3$-Combinations for a $4$-digits set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider we have $4$ digits. We want to compute the $3$ digit combinations of these $4$ digits ($1-2-3-4$).

From the formula, we have:

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{4!}{3!1!} = 4$$

but when I try to write it down, I only find 3 combinations:

$$123-124-234$$

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing $134$.

An easy way to make sure you have all of them is to note that each $3$ digit combination corresponds to choosing $1$ digit to leave out. So $134$ corresponds to leaving out $2$, and so on. Since you can leave out $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$, there are $4$ different combinations of $3$ digits, and you can list them explicitly by excluding $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ from the digits.

Comment: I see. Such an obvious mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

Omit each digit in turn. You forgot `134`.